# [STM32F103RB][C] - DMA, can't change PWM period

Tags: pwm, c, stm32, dma

Hello i woul'd like change PWM period with DMA. I wrote code but i don't know why LED BLINKING with constant time

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_nucleo.h"
#include "stm32f10x.h"

int i =0;
u16 PWM_Buf[198];

void TIMInit(void);
void GPIOInit(void);
void DMAInit(void);
void PWMInit(void);

int main(void)
{
 GPIOInit();
 TIMInit();
 DMAInit();
 PWMInit();

 for(i = 0;i<198;i++)
 {
  PWM_Buf[i] = i * 10; // <-------- VALUE OF TIM PERIOD
 }


    while(1)
    {
    }
}
void TIMInit(void)
{
 TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIMInit;

 RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1, ENABLE);

    TIMInit.TIM_Period = 1000;
    TIMInit.TIM_Prescaler = 64000;

    TIMInit.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIMInit.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;

    TIMInit.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 200;

    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1, &TIMInit);
}

void GPIOInit(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOInit;

 RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
 RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);

   GPIOInit.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
   GPIOInit.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
   GPIOInit.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;

   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIOInit);
}

void DMAInit(void)
{
 #define TIM1_ARR_Address 0X40012C2C

 DMA_InitTypeDef DMAInit;

 RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);
 DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel5);
 DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (u16)TIM1_ARR_Address;
 DMAInit.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (u32)PWM_Buf;
 DMAInit.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
 DMAInit.DMA_BufferSize = 198;
 DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Enable;
 DMAInit.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
 DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Word;
 DMAInit.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
 DMAInit.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
 DMAInit.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
 DMAInit.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;

 DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel5, &DMAInit);

    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel5, ENABLE);
}

void PWMInit(void)
{
 TIM_OCInitTypeDef  PWMInit;

    PWMInit.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    PWMInit.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    PWMInit.TIM_Pulse = 500;
    PWMInit.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM1, &PWMInit);
    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM1, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM1, ENABLE);
    TIM_DMACmd(TIM1, TIM_DMA_Update, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM1, ENABLE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the full source code along with the question.

Comment: It's not full code i cutted usart communication, and motor driver. I only paste DMA TIMER AND PWM configuration. I thought i wrote good code but i dont know why period doesnt be diffrent. I need only help for it.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? `DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Enable;` Does this really want to be set to inc? I suspect this is at least one issue you have and it wants to be `DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable`. I think.

Comment: It's not probably problem i disabled this and the same. I don't see anything wrong. I thought someone maybe caught problem

Comment: You need to put @DiBosco for me to see your response. When I did this to create PWMs many years back, my DMA's CPAR register was set to the CCR, not the ARR register which I *think* you have used here.

Answer (score 1):

```
DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (u16)TIM1_ARR_Address;
```

You can't cast a pointer as an unsigned 16 bit. Pointers are 32 bit on this platform.
Like this: `(uint32_t)&TIM1->ARR`.

```
DMAInit.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Enable;
```

You can't increment the peripheral address, the next cycle would be TIMx_RCR, then TIMx_CCR1 etc.

Comment: I'd already pointed out the peripheral inc thing to him and he'd said that'd made no difference. The pointer thing is good point though.

Comment: I know it's stupid, but can I ask for the code to be corrected because I have no idea how to do it. I would be very grateful

Comment: I wonder how you wrote this code if you have no idea what to change or at least articulate yourself to ask what to change!!?

Comment: @MemberCicada why have you configured PeripheralDataSize as word and MemoryDataSize as half word?

Comment: @charansai the timer is 16 bit and half word access is possible.